# How to retrive attribute value if user clicked on child element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone tell me how to retrive `data-custom` attribute value if i click on the red square?I dont want to place the same attribute in child because its getting verbose if i have more&deeper nested elements.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  render(){
  
    return (
    
      <div className="large-box" data-custom="iExist" onClick={this.onClick}>
      
        <div className="box red"></div>
      
      </div>
    
    )
  
  }
  
  onClick(e){
  
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-custom'))
  
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.large-box {
  display:flex;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;

}

.box {
  margin:auto auto;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;

}

.red{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the value to `onClick` funtion directly? `onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'custom-value') }`

Comment: I have read thats its bad practice because its creating new function each time react render function is evaluated which can lead to performance issues.I were wondering how much i should care about performance because binding or using `()=>{}` function sound like easy way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple - use `event.currentTarget`

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

`Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.`

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  render(){
  
    return (
    
      <div className="large-box" data-custom="iExist" onClick={this.onClick}>
      
        <div className="box red"></div>
      
      </div>
    
    )
  
  }
  
  onClick(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-custom'))
  
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.large-box {
  display:flex;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;

}

.box {
  margin:auto auto;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;

}

.red{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: That what i were looking for!

Comment: @JanCiołek only thing to watch out for here is that Safar 9 and lower does not support this.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for the attribute `data-custom` using `hasAttibute` method. If attribute not present than get it from `parentNode`.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  render(){
  
    return (
    
      <div className="large-box" data-custom="iExist" onClick={this.onClick}>
      
        <div className="box red"></div>
      
      </div>
    
    )
  
  }
  
  onClick(e){
  
    console.log(e.target.hasAttribute('data-custom')?e.target.getAttribute('data-custom'):e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-custom'))
  
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.large-box {
  display:flex;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;

}

.box {
  margin:auto auto;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;

}

.red{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah that would do the trick and even if the nesting level isnt static i can make some loop to lurk for attribute.Thanks!

Comment: Don't make loop. Either create recursive function for this.

Comment: Thats even better!

Comment: Either solution would be overly complicated for something that is already present. As totbar indicated in his answer, you can simply use `event.currentTarget` which will return the element on which the event was defined.